# Relative path from applicationsettings inside web.config

Tags: asp.net, dll, iis-7, web-config

I have a DLL that provides mail sending functionality to an asp.net application, this DLL reads its configuration from an xml file whose path is set in an app.config setting.

I ported the configuration into an applicationsettings section inside my web.config:

```
  <applicationSettings>
      <MyNamespace.MailLibrary.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="MailTemplatesConfigurationPath" serializeAs="String">
          <value>**./_mail/MailTemplatesConfiguration.xml**</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SenderAddress" serializeAs="String">
          <value>noreply@mydomain.com</value>
        </setting>
      </MyNamespace.MailLibrary.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Everything works but I cannot find a way to specify a path relative to the webapp root, `MailTemplatesConfigurationPath` value is always relative to IIS root, so:

```
./_mail/MailTemplatesConfiguration.xml
```

becomes

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\_mail\MailTemplatesConfiguration.xml
```

Is there any way to reference the root path of the web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue is that you don't want server.MapPath in the dll, have the function that uses this value accept another parameter for the rootPath which can be passed in from the calling code. The calling code, which is not in the dll, can use MapPath to get the rootPath value.

Comment: You're right, I don't want the component to be tied to a web-app env... I was looking for a more "clean" solution (and I think there is one, even if I don't have time now to find it :S ) but in the end the idea of passing the base root as dependency is good. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<value>**~/_mail/MailTemplatesConfiguration.xml**</value>
```

Also, you may find the following link useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Comment: Did you try Server.MapPath("~")? Providing the code that tries to resolve could be somewhat helpful

Comment: The code that loads the xml file is in the DLL, so I don't want to use Server.MapPath there. Anyway I'll post the snippet as you suggested.